# How do I work-around a bug in Emacs related to editing Lisp files after opening Verilog files?

Tags: emacs, lisp, verilog

In emacs, usually `ctrl-meta-q` works just fine for auto-indenting comments that are prefixed with `;;` in Lisp files.  However, once I open a Verilog file, `ctrl-meta-q` pushes the comment all the way to the left margin.  How do I keep Verilog mode from interfering with the way `;;` comments should be handled in Lisp mode?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the verilog-mode. If the latest version doesn't work, then file an issue with a testcase. http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-mode

Comment: Using a fresh emacs session, in a LISP mode buffer, hit `ctrl-h k ctrl-meta-q` to see what function is mapped to C-M-q (it is `indent-sexp` on my system. Then visit a verilog file, return to the LISP file and do it again. Are the two results different? If so, you could add a lisp-mode hook to re-establish the correct function as a work-around.

Comment: @greg unfortunately I'm stuck on an old distribution, which might be part of the problem

Comment: @GavinLock good idea, thanks.  Unfortunately it's the same both before and after, so I'm still wondering.